# threeJS reinit controls and keep camera position

Tags: three.js

using threeJS to create a sphere with a 360 image.
init with:

`this.controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(this.camera, true);`

and on click I change controls to OrbitControls.

Is there a way to keep/find current camera position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

results achieved by combining DeviceOrientationControls and OrbitControls, together with controls enable/disable toggle, below.

`this.controls.enabled = !this.controls.enabled;`